# Animate a WPF Window left and right with a shake effect?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, wpf-controls

Could someone please show me how to animate a window from its current position.  I am looking for a shake effect which simply shakes the window left and right say 5 to 6 times.

I understand that I need to use Animation.By.  This is something I have started but am not getting far.

**This However does not work.**

```
<Storyboard x:Key="sbShake1" FillBehavior="Stop">
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="W1" Storyboard.TargetProperty ="(Window.Left)"
                     By="10" Duration="0:0:1">
    </DoubleAnimation >
</Storyboard >
```

I have managed to get the right shake effect but I cannot do it from the windows current position.

```
<Storyboard x:Key="sbShake" RepeatBehavior ="00:00:01" SpeedRatio ="25" >
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty ="Left">
        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime ="00:00:00.1000000" Value ="-10"/>
        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime ="00:00:00.3000000" Value ="0"/>
        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime ="00:00:00.5000000" Value ="10"/>
        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime ="00:00:00.7000000" Value ="0"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames >
</Storyboard >
```

All help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the Left property of your window to 500 and add this code:

```
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.MouseDown" >
        <EventTrigger.Actions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard TargetProperty="Left">
                    <DoubleAnimation From="500" To="515" Duration="0:0:0.05"
                                     AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="3x"
                                     FillBehavior="Stop"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger.Actions>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

You should set the property `Left` of `Window` manually when you don't mention `From="x"` otherwise it set to Auto and when you try to shake your window the value of Left is NaN and an exception will be thrown.

Comment: It has been a long time but I have just come back to this.  Thank you Ali.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [a BounceEase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.bounceease.aspx) to make the window shake:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="myStoryboard">
    <DoubleAnimation By="10" Duration="00:00:3"
                     AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="1"
                     Storyboard.TargetName="W1" 
                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Left">
        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
            <BounceEase Bounces="2" EasingMode="EaseOut" 
                        Bounciness="2" />
        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
    </DoubleAnimation>
</Storyboard>
```

Comment: For me this only works with a `From` value too. Otherwise Window will keep moving to the right out of sight.

Comment: Ah sorry to both.  My first code snippet does in fact not work.  It does keep going off the screen.  I have edited me original post.  I am not sure the BounceEase is the kind of shake I am looking for.  This shake indicates an error so would prefer just a left right movement of equal size, speed etc.

Comment: Just make sure you set autoreverse property to true and repeat property correct

Comment: Thank you for updating your email.  But it still just goes off the screen.  I have found similar code here in my search so what else do I have to set? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a40f7e0f-f1cc-410b-9b5f-eb0b46b085e7/problem-during-moving-window-using-doubleanimation

Comment: ElasticEase is better for this purpose (shaking effect). And no need for AutoReverse — instead of "By" use From="-100" To="0" so it will jump to the original position from some distance and then oscillate.